# How to extract values from a json object with spaces using jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, sh, jq

I have the below JSON string with multiple JSON objects. I would like to extract just the id and name from each object and print it.

```json
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "John Wick",
      "location": "USA"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Walter White",
      "location": "USA"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using the below code to extract the id and name using 'jq'

```bash
for key in $(jq -c '.users | .[]' sample.json); do
  id=$(jq -r '.id' <<< "$key");
  name=$(jq -r '.name' <<< "$key")
  echo $id $name
done
```

But I am getting parsing errors like below. Can someone help me with this?

> ```
> parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
> ```

I tried replacing spaces with a combination of special chars and replace again special chars with spaces. It worked for me but I need a better solution than this.

Comment: can you try this :   cat jsonfile  |  jq -r "(.users[]| .id ,  .name)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 2 `read`'s to capture the values, we can let JQ loop over the objects, and output the `id` and `name`. :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
jq -r -c '.users[] | .id, .name' /tmp/input3 | while read -r id && read -r name; do
    echo -e "ID: ${id}\t Name: ${name}"
done
```

Output:

```
ID: 1    Name: John Wick
ID: 2    Name: Walter White
```

Comment: Or simply: `jq -r -c '.users[] | .id, .name' sample.json  | paste - -`

Comment: Thanks! This helped me to solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

You can use the csv or tsv features of jq - lots of great examples in the man page!

```bash
man jq
```

Try this:

```bash
jq -r '.users[] | [.id , .name] | @csv' sample.json
```

Example output:

```bash
$ jq -r '.users[] | [.id , .name] | @csv' sample.json
"1","John Wick"
"2","Walter White"
```

Or using string interpolation:

```bash
$ jq -r '.users[] | [.id, .name] | "\(.[0]) \(.[1])"' sample.json
1 John Wick
2 Walter White
```

Comment: You can do simpler: `jq -rc '.users[] | "\(.id) \(.name)" ' sample.json` !!

Comment: @F.Hauri Even simpler: Drop `-c` (and the final whitespace). The use of `-r` renders compact formatting obsolete.